# How to manage app badge count with local notification and push notifications within the same application?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, push-notification, localnotification

I have one iOS application in which I implemented both local notifications and push notifications.

I am able to manage push notifications badge count using notification service extension and saving the badg count in NSUserDefaults. And push notifications I am able to handle using UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate methods in foreground and background; but when the local notification get fired on scheduled time then it overrides the app badge count when app is in background.

I can manage the app badge count when app is in foreground using UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
method with local and push notification.

There is no other way I found to manage the app badge count with local notification when app is in background.

So my question is how to manage app badge count with both local notification and push notification within the same application.

Please help me with this point.

Thanks in advance.